# Are the memory mapped IO address(es) of a device mapped to the kernel space of a process?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, operating-system

Say that I have a device that uses memory mapped IO.

And we know that in Linux, each process have 3 GB of user space, and 1 GB of kernel space.

Now I assume that the address(es) for this device will be mapped to the kernel space of a process, so that a process (which is running in user mode) cannot access the device. Am I correct?

Comment: You're assuming a 32-bit OS, right?

Comment: @David Schwartz Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I assume that the address(es) for this device will be mapped to the kernel space of a process, so that a process (which is running in user mode) cannot access the device. Am I correct?

Mostly. Since devices exist in physical memory, they can be mapped to multiple virtual addresses. An appropriately privileged userspace application can use `mmap()` on `/dev/mem` to remap portions of I/O memory into its address spce.